# How I integrate two dropdown in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have 2 dropdown in same screen, called dropdown A and B.
Dropdown A consist of 3 elements, called 1,2 and 3.
While dropdown B consist of 7 elements, which 1st until 5th elements of Dropdown B will only open, if 1st element of dropdown A was choosed. The 6th and 7th elements of Dropdown B will only open, if 2nd element of dropdown A was choosed. And if The 3rd element of dropdown A was choosed, a textinput will generated automatically in screen.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried to build 2 drop down:

Comment: let kategori = [
    { value: 'Dokumen Berharga', id:"DokumenBerharga" }, 
    { value: 'Dokumen Biasa', id:"DokumenBiasa" }, 
    { value: 'Paket', id:"Paket" }, 
    { value: 'Lainnya', id:"Lainnya" }
  ];

Comment: let deskripsi = [
    { value: 'BPKB Mobil', id:"BPKBMobil" }, 
    { value: 'BPKB Motor', id:"BPKBMotor" }, 
    { value: 'STNK Mobil', id:"STNKMobil" }, 
    { value: 'STNK Motor', id:"STNKMotor" }, 
    { value: 'Ijazah', id:"Ijazah" }, 
    { value: 'Pasport', id:"Pasport" }, 
    { value: 'Sertifikat Tanah Asli', id:"SertifikatTanah" }, 
  ];

Comment: <Dropdown
                        label='Kategori Barang'
                        data={kategori}
                        // value={this.state.kategori_barang}
                    />
                    <Dropdown
                        label='Sub-Kategori/Deskripsi'
                        data={deskripsi}
                    />

Comment: I call them one by one. But, they haven't integrated yet

Comment: "What have you tried so far?"  was a comment intended to guide you to improving your question.  You are expected to edit your question with any content you are trying to add, not just add it here with comments.